# Need Help for TabHost Design

Tags: android, xml, android-tabhost, android-style-tabhost

[image: Originally I need like this]

[image: My currant tabhost is]

I need My TabHost Look like That First One.
Xml file code for Corner is :

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"/>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#88a9a9a9"
                android:endColor="#000"
                android:gradientRadius="400"
                android:angle="270"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="#880f0f10"
                android:centerColor="#8858585a"
                android:endColor="#88a9a9a9"/>
            <corners
                android:topRightRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item></selector>
```

Java code line :

mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundcorner);`

Comment: what is your problem  ?

Comment: what is the problem??

Comment: I need Output as First Image .

Comment: @Kate4Help see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this way,
for left side First one :-

```
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"/>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#880f0f10"
            android:endColor="#000"
            android:gradientRadius="400"
            android:angle="-270"/>
        <stroke android:width="3px" android:color="@color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:startColor="#CCCCCC"
            android:centerColor="#CCCCCC"
            android:endColor="#CCCCCC"/>
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"/>
        <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="@color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Right side Last one :-

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:topRightRadius="5dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#880f0f10"
                android:endColor="#000"
                android:gradientRadius="400"
                android:angle="-270"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="#CCCCCC"
                android:centerColor="#CCCCCC"
                android:endColor="#CCCCCC"/>
            <corners
                android:topRightRadius="5dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="@color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item></selector>
```

for center

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#880f0f10"
                android:endColor="#000"
                android:gradientRadius="400"
                android:angle="-270"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="#CCCCCC"
                android:centerColor="#CCCCCC"
                android:endColor="#CCCCCC"/>
            <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="@color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item></selector>
```

and in Java

```
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundcorner_tab_left);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundcorner_tab_center);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundcorner_tab_right);
```

Comment: I am not getting this because i need changes in my TabHost. RadioButton and bla bla is there .

Comment: i gave answer as per your expected view,and you can also manage with radiobutton too..

Comment: @Kate4Help see my edited answer and let me know is it working or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104494/discussion-between-kate-4-help-and-aditya).

Comment: @Kate4Help did you try with my answer??